# How do you add values between a certain date and time period in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I need to work out how many hours were worked on a night shift, between the hours of 22:00 and 06:00 on a daily basis - this obviously goes over 2 dates.

So for instance 01/10/2017 22:00 to 02/10/2017 06:00. I've tried SUMIFS and SUMPRODUCT but I'm not having much luck.

Comment: (1) Please say 01-Oct-2017 or Jan 10, 2017, so we know what you mean.   (2) I want to compute a function; for example, f(42).  How do I do it?  You can’t tell without knowing what result I want for f(42), can you?  So please tell us the result you want for your example input.

Comment: Please also add some more sample data with desired output, that would help us to understand your issue.

Comment: Taking a guess about what you're trying to do:  Subtracting the start date from the end date will give you the number of days (or fraction of a day) between the two dates. Multiply by 24 to get the number of hours.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fairly simple formula;

```
=SUM(EndTime - StartTime)*24
```

For this, I put the start time in `A1` and the end time in `B1`. Then the formula in `C1`.

[image]

(Oops. I didn't use the same hours as you, but I think you get the point.)